# BlueRemSwitch has Stop

Tags: java, android, eclipse, bluetooth, arduino

I downloaded a project called BlueremSwitch and when I run it I got this error,I dont know whats the problem and I am a beginner in android development ,could I ask for Help?
My phone says,unfortunately BlueRem Switch has stopped,Please I am asking for help..Please

```
01-05 03:53:52.356: E/AndroidRuntime(27851): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-05 03:53:52.356: E/AndroidRuntime(27851): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-05 03:53:52.356: E/AndroidRuntime(27851):    at Android.Arduino.Bluetooth.BluetoothTest.openBT(BluetoothTest.java:152)
01-05 03:53:52.356: E/AndroidRuntime(27851):    at Android.Arduino.Bluetooth.BluetoothTest$1.onClick(BluetoothTest.java:59)
01-05 03:53:52.356: E/AndroidRuntime(27851):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4212)
01-05 03:53:52.356: E/AndroidRuntime(27851):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17476)
01-05 03:53:52.356: E/AndroidRuntime(27851):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:800)
01-05 03:53:52.356: E/AndroidRuntime(27851):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
01-05 03:53:52.356: E/AndroidRuntime(27851):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
01-05 03:53:52.356: E/AndroidRuntime(27851):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
01-05 03:53:52.356: E/AndroidRuntime(27851):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-05 03:53:52.356: E/AndroidRuntime(27851):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
01-05 03:53:52.356: E/AndroidRuntime(27851):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
01-05 03:53:52.356: E/AndroidRuntime(27851):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
01-05 03:53:52.356: E/AndroidRuntime(27851):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

this is the Bluethootest.java

```
package Android.Arduino.Bluetooth;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.EditText;  
import android.widget.Button;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.UUID;

public class BluetoothTest extends Activity
{
    TextView myLabel;
    EditText myTextbox;
    BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
    BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    BluetoothDevice mmDevice;
    OutputStream mmOutputStream;
    InputStream mmInputStream;
    Thread workerThread;
    byte[] readBuffer;
    int readBufferPosition;
    int counter;
    volatile boolean stopWorker;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button openButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.open);
       // Button sendButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.send);
        Button closeButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.close);
        Button onButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.onButton);
        Button offButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.offButton);

        myLabel = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.label);
       // myTextbox = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.entry);

        //Open Button
        openButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                try 
                {
                    findBT();
                    openBT();
                }
                catch (IOException ex) { }
            }
        });

        //Send Button
        /*sendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                try 
                {
                    sendData();
                }
                catch (IOException ex) { }
            }
        });*/

        //ON SWITCH
        onButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    onButton();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                }

            }
        });

      //OFF SWITCH
        offButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    offButton();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                }

            }
        });

        //Close button
        closeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                try 
                {
                    closeBT();
                }
                catch (IOException ex) { }
            }
        });
    }

    void findBT()
    {
        mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        if(mBluetoothAdapter == null)
        {
            myLabel.setText("No bluetooth adapter available");
        }

        if(!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled())
        {
            Intent enableBluetooth = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableBluetooth, 0);
        }

        Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
        if(pairedDevices.size() > 0)
        {
            for(BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices)
            {
                if(device.getName().equals("linvor")) 
                {
                    mmDevice = device;
                    Log.v("ArduinoBT", "findBT found device named " + mmDevice.getName());
                    Log.v("ArduinoBT", "device address is " + mmDevice.getAddress());
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        myLabel.setText("Bluetooth Device Found");
    }

    void openBT() throws IOException
    {
        UUID uuid = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"); //Standard SerialPortService ID
        mmSocket = mmDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);        
        mmSocket.connect();
        mmOutputStream = mmSocket.getOutputStream();
        mmInputStream = mmSocket.getInputStream();

        beginListenForData();

        myLabel.setText("Bluetooth Opened");
    }

    void beginListenForData()
    {
        final Handler handler = new Handler(); 
        final byte delimiter = 10; //This is the ASCII code for a newline character

        stopWorker = false;
        readBufferPosition = 0;
        readBuffer = new byte[1024];
        workerThread = new Thread(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {                
               while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() && !stopWorker)
               {
                    try 
                    {
                        int bytesAvailable = mmInputStream.available();                        
                        if(bytesAvailable > 0)
                        {
                            byte[] packetBytes = new byte[bytesAvailable];
                            mmInputStream.read(packetBytes);
                            for(int i=0;i<bytesAvailable;i++)
                            {
                                byte b = packetBytes[i];
                                if(b == delimiter)
                                {
                                    byte[] encodedBytes = new byte[readBufferPosition];
                                    System.arraycopy(readBuffer, 0, encodedBytes, 0, encodedBytes.length);
                                    final String data = new String(encodedBytes, "US-ASCII");
                                    readBufferPosition = 0;

                                    handler.post(new Runnable()
                                    {
                                        public void run()
                                        {
                                            myLabel.setText(data);
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    readBuffer[readBufferPosition++] = b;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } 
                    catch (IOException ex) 
                    {
                        stopWorker = true;
                    }
               }
            }
        });

        workerThread.start();
    }

    void sendData() throws IOException
    {
        String msg = myTextbox.getText().toString();
        msg += "\0";
        //mmOutputStream.write(msg.getBytes());
        //mmOutputStream.write(msg.getBytes());
        //mmOutputStream.flush();
        //mmOutputStream.close();
        //mmSocket.close();
        myLabel.setText("Data Sent"+msg);
    }

    void onButton() throws IOException
    {
        mmOutputStream.write("1".getBytes());
    }

    void offButton() throws IOException
    {
        mmOutputStream.write("2".getBytes());
    }

    void closeBT() throws IOException
    {
        stopWorker = true;
        mmOutputStream.close();
        mmInputStream.close();
        mmSocket.close();
        myLabel.setText("Bluetooth Closed");
    }
}
```

Comment: A little bit of the code where this 'error' happens would be very nicely...

Comment: plz post the BluetoothTest.java class.

Comment: BlueRem? maybe is it BlueTerm? Because I'm aware of this one (got it working). I also tried BlueScripts, which is also very good and a tutorial from a russian guy (2 tutorials, only the 2nd working - search for BOLUTEK)

Comment: sorry I mispellef it,its BlueremSwitch..I'm done editing my post..I hope you can help me..please I need help..please

Comment: Without knowing which line is 152, it is probably either mmDevice is null or it wasn't able to create mmSocket so that is null

Comment: Does the code execute findBT before it executes openBT?  Is the device name linvor?  The code at the end of findBT will tell you that a device has been found even though it hasn't.  Shift your setText statement before the break.